# Printing a variable in python doesn't work / How to simplyfiy this script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been **trying to print a variable** (in a loop, to count down each round) ...

Has anyone Idea to help me, because it shows me **every time  "IndentationError: expected an indented block"** and says the error is at the print line...

And another question: Has someone an idea, how to for simplify a YouTube-viewbot?

Here's the Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

Timer = 15
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S8s1QTLhHs&t=99s"
views = 3
count = 1
a = views

driver1 = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\samue\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\samue\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver3 = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\samue\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver4 = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\samue\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
driver5 = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\samue\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')

driver1.get(link)
driver2.get(link)
driver3.get(link)
driver4.get(link)
driver5.get(link)

for i in range(views):
    time.sleep(Timer)
    driver1.refresh()
    driver2.refresh()
    driver3.refresh()
    driver4.refresh()
    driver5.refresh()
    while a >= 0:
    print(a, "views left")
    a += -1


driver1.quit()
driver2.quit()
driver3.quit()
driver4.quit()
driver5.quit()
```

Comment: Exactly as the error says: you have created a `while` loop, so the commands inside the loop, starting with `print` need to be indented

Comment: Also, you can use `a -= 1` rather than `a += -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the error message, an indentation block is missing. The while loop should look like:

```
while a >= 0:
    print(a, "views left")
    a -= 1
```